# CSS for Table Header with auto-sized trailing underline

Tags: css

Using only HTML and CSS,
I wish to have a table like the following:

```
  Header1          Header2
  --------------   --------------------
  L1Col1 content   L1Col2 wider content
  L2Col1 datum     L2Col2 datum2

Where the underline automatically sizes to the
table column width.

Help!
```

Comment: What have you already done? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @italant Perhaps, but asking us for doing the work is not a good thing. People should make an attempt to solve the problem themselves first and, if necessary, ask about a specific problem amidst the process. Stack Overflow is here for that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CSS:

```
.sample-table {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    border-spacing: 25px 0;
}
.sample-table th {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000; 
}
.sample-table td,
.sample-table th {
    padding: 3px;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="sample-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>L1Col1 content</td>
    <td>L1Col2 wider content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>L2Col1 datum</td>
    <td>L2Col2 datum2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Azu,
Thanks for your answer.
The "border-spacing" usage was completely enlightening to me.
I modified the CSS to the following:

```
.sample-table {
    text-align: left;
    border-spacing: 25px 0;
}
.sample-table th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.sample-table td,
.sample-table th {
    padding: 3px 0px;
}
```

This gives me exactly what I wanted.